# Principal components of square

Tags: pca, geometry

I am trying to compute the first two principal components of a parallelogram with vertices (0,0), (2,0), (1,1), (3,1) of uniform density, as well as their variances. The obvious choices appear to be the two diagonals. However, I am not sure how to prove this, and how to compute the variances of these components.

Comment: The diagonals of this parallelogram can't be the two principal components, because they're not orthogonal. You have a vector $[X_1, X_2]$. The dot product with vector $w = [w_1, w_2]$ is $Z = w_1 X_1 + w_2 X_2$. You know the joint density of $X_1$ and $X_2$, so you can use this to find an expression for the density of $Z$. Use this to find the variance of the projection as a function of $w$. Then, find $w$ with norm 1 that maximizes the variance. This is the first PC. The second PC is just a vector orthogonal to this.

Comment: A more straightforward approach simply is to compute the relevant moments by direct integration over the parallelogram and perform PCA on the $2\times 2$ variance matrix.